# On send mail define a specific reply mail adress

Tags: joomla-3.x

I want to know if there is a way in Joomla! when sending mail to define a specific adress mail for reply ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use addReplyTo, eg.

```
$mailer->addReplyTo("me@example.com", "Head Office");
```

Here it is in the API doc:

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Mail.Mail.html#method_addReplyTo